# How to enable "www." for my domain

Tags: web, dns, hosting

I've recently bought a domain for my website the naked domain is linked correctly to my website for example: http://domainname.com goes to my host space and loads my site. Although this works I can't seem to load the site when I type in http://www.domainname.com. Is there am extra step I need to take or is there something I need to activate on my domains DNS setting to make my site load when I add www.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

You need to add an A type record for www subdomain.

If you let us know which nameserver provider you're using we can probably find you or write up a step by step short tutorial, if you need one.

Also, I removed "google" from your question title. You have not bought a "google domain", you simply bought a "domain"

Comment: Hey Eedoh thanks for the response, my name provider is google domians "https://domains.google"

Comment: You're welcome. Check this link out https://support.google.com/domains/answer/3290350?hl=en and expand "Record sets" section. When adding the new record set, use www for it's name and of course use your site's address instead of the addresses listed in the example. Let me know if that worked, please. Also, bear in mind that it may take some time for your change to propagate, don't be surprised if it does not start working right away.